# Haxe use of @:classCode

Tags: java, haxe

I can't find a single example of how `@:classCode` is used (to inject a native member directly into the file). This fails with `Unexpected untyped` at compile time:

```
@:classCode
untyped __java__("public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {doStuff();}");
```

I can't simply use standard Haxe code to have a `paintComponent()` method because of the way Haxe eats `@:overload` methods (and forces use of `@:overload` in the first place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some examples of it [in the Haxe standard library](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%40%3AclassCode), for instance:

```
@:classCode('override public string Message { get { return this.toString(); } }\n\n')
@:nativeGen @:keep @:native("haxe.lang.HaxeException")
private class HaxeException extends Exception
```

Looks like the class code metadata has a string argument containing the code to be inserted and should be used on a class declaration.